# Trying to write an iterative dynamic programming solution to the travelling salesman problem (python)

Tags: python, iteration, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to write an iterative dynamic programming solution to the travelling salesman problem, building up the solution from the solutions to subproblems. However, I am finding this a bit challenging and I've run into a lot of bugs. One of which is `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min_distance' referenced before assignment`, although I can't pinpoint why, since looking over it, it looks like I've defined it before it's used.

This is my code:

```
import itertools
distances = [[0, 10, 11, 8, 16, 20],
            [10, 0, 5, 4, 9, 6],
            [11, 5, 0, 7, 11, 14],
            [8, 4, 7, 0, 6, 15],
            [16, 9, 11, 6, 0, 7],
            [20, 6, 14, 15, 7, 0]]

cities = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

def obtain_distance(city1, city2):
    return distances[int(city1)][int(city2)]

memo_table = dict()

#the home city is implemented as '0' here.
def iterative_held_karp(cities, memo_table):

     if len(cities)==0:
         return 0
    
     for subset_size in range(2, len(cities)+1):
          for comb in itertools.combinations(cities, subset_size):
               #now consider a test city and the cities without the test city

               min_distance = float('inf')
               for test_city in comb:

                    cities_without_test_city = frozenset([city for city in cities if city != test_city])
                    
                    for next_city in cities_without_test_city:
                         test_dist = obtain_distance(test_city, next_city)
                         next_cities = frozenset([city for city in cities_without_test_city if city != next_city])

                         if next_cities == []:
                              dist = obtain_distance(next_city, '0')
                         elif (next_city, frozenset(next_cities)) in memo_table:
                              dist = memo_table[(next_city, frozenset(next_cities))]
                         else:
                              dist = iterative_held_karp(cities_without_test_city, memo_table)

                         computed_distance = test_dist + dist
                         min_distance = min(computed_distance, min_distance)
                    
                    memo_table[(test_city, frozenset(cities_without_test_city))] = min_distance
                
     return min_distance
```